# Can I release all my copyrighted works into the public domain upon my death?

Tags: united-states, wills, public-domain

I would like all my copyrighted works into the public domain immediately upon my death (rather than the current United States law specifying that it will be released 70 years after my death). Is this possible to do, for instance by putting a statement to that effect in my last will and testament?

To clarify, I would like this to be for all works not otherwise specified in my will, including those unpublished. For instance, if I scribbled something on the back of a napkin that becomes valuable after my death, I want it to be in the public domain instead of retaining copyright.

Comment: Great idea, so if you have any works of value, your kids will be without money at age 10.

Comment: @gnasher729 My primary source of income is not derived from works that I own copyright for, and to be honest, I doubt that any of it would have any monetary value. It's more about the principle than anything else. Rest assured, when I have kids some day, I will make sure that they will be provided for in the event of my death, regardless of my feelings about releasing copyrighted works into the public domain. Who knows? I may change my mind and decide they can benefit from my stuff until they are 40.

Comment: @gnasher729: I don't think it's appropriate to criticize someone's choices on this forum.  There are plenty of people in the world who choose to donate assets for the public good rather than leaving them to their heirs, so it's not as though this is an utterly absurd notion.

Comment: Technically, your copyrights last 70 years after your death regardless of who owns them or whether you or your heirs have any intention of enforcing them. You may certainly document your irrevocable permission for everyone to freely use them forever, such as various constructs under Creative Commons (i.e., CC0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under US copyright law, all works are protected by copyright except for [US Government works](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/105). The concept of "public domain" is not legally well-defined, and is used colloquially to refer to government works, works whose protection has expired, works available to all, and works not copyrightable (such as scientific laws or old software). Under older copyright law, releasing a work without the copyright symbol effectively put the work in the public domain.

One can simply say "I dedicate this work to the public domain", and that is typically taken to be enough. CC0 purports to do this (using more words). However, as far as I can tell, author rights under European law are so strong that it is simply impossible. Releasing works into the public law has to be consistent with other aspects of the law. If you grant an perpetual exclusive right to copy and distribute to a publisher, their right does not go away on your death (a right which they would not have with a real public domain work).

A problem is that an author who makes such a dedication (a bare license) could revoke the license and reassert their copyright. They could be estopped from making that argument. As property, your heirs would inherit the copyright and could (try to) revoke the license. Presumably the courts would not allow them to pursue ostensive infringers. Nevertheless, your plan is neither trivial nor bullet-proof.

Comment: For those looking for a citation after "that is typically taken to be enough", at least for US law Daniel J. Bernstein has written a rather nice analysis, including what seems to be the most salient decision from the 9th Circuit: https://cr.yp.to/publicdomain.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

If you write a will, putting all your work titles under CC0 and announce it "**irrevocable**", and publicly distributing those works via websites (youtube, flickr gives you option to choose the license you want; as for text, just put it up in a website or blog and claim it CC0), adding irrevocable CC0 copyright claim.  And you've got it Public Domain technically.

BUT if your work is previously published via other publishers, that's another story.

I think content creators should learn from your generosity.  I'm using CC works to build content and I think once you've done that, your work will be spread all over the world.

Some people claimed that it won't work in Europe.  Well, isn't it a basic human right for the creator of the content to decide how the work should be disbtributed?

- Adding CC0:  https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/
  All you need to do is announce it and release it to CC0.

Comment: "Well, isn't it a basic human right for the creator of the content to decide how the work should be disbtributed?" according to what?

Comment: Basic human rights means it's not GIVEN, it's BORN WITH.  Do you need a law to decide if your very existence is legal?

Comment: I meant is there widely accepted definition that covers this? I couldn't find anything in the [UN Universal Declaration of Human Rights](https://www.un.org/en/universal-declaration-human-rights). Article 3 for your example btw, though I'm not sure what that has to do with copyright.

Comment: Again you resolve to some regulations....and with China and Iran in the "human rights counsel",  how right is that.

Comment: Can I ask what point you're trying to make here?

Comment: "[I]sn't it a basic human right...?" Sadly, even the governments of Europe struggle with what should be basic human rights.